# Strange output when importing JSON to Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

As the question says, I get an unexpected output when importing JSON into a TableView class.

JSON:

```
{"city":"Cambridge"}{"city":"Oxford"}
```

Objective-C:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/cities.php"]];
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", response);
```

Output:

```
<7b226369 7479223a 2243616d 62726964 6765227d 7b226369 7479223a 224f7866 6f726422 7d>
```

Fairly sure I'm structuring my JSON wrongly...

Comment: Although the initial problem you described is simply that you're logging an instance of NSData, as noted in several answers, the JSON you posted isn't structured correctly, so you won't be able to deserialize it with `NSJSONSerialization` unless you fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your response is of NSData type and needs to be converted to a string.

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[response bytes] length:[response length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(responseString);
```

You can also use the initWithData as described elsewhere

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

While this is useful for debugging, to actually extract or work with the data, you will want to convert it to dictionary or array.

```
NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:NULL];
```

From here, you can reference items in the dictionary.

Comment: Why not convert it to an array or dictionary using `NSJSONSerialization`?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do. I'm assuming he is expecting to see the JSON, not a dictionary representation of the JSON.

Comment: If it makes a difference I'm hoping to display them in a UITableView object.

Comment: Why assume that? Your answer will be more helpful if you include `NSJSONSerialization`.

Comment: Well put. Answer amended.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *responseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",responseArray);
NSMutableArray *cityArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i<[responseArray count]; i++)
{
    [cityArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[responseArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"city"];
}
```

Please note that, I believe you would fix that json and make it to json returning an array.

Answer (score -2):

```
NSString *jsonStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@",jsonStr);
```